# asp.net c# browse to folder instead of file

Tags: c#, asp.net

can i by using input ==file browse to **folder only** not folder plus file 
or by any other means.

I have to give path in textbox for some Website package to unzip(that contains all the folders and files need to initialize a website). By giving that many checks have to be implemented like path exists.

It would be nice if the user just selects the folder he created for the website package to be unzipped.

Comment: what you are looking for? please explain bit more

Comment: well i had to give path in textbox for some Website package to unzip(that contains all the folders and files need to initialize a website). By giving that many checks has to be implemented like path exists and so on . it would be nice if the user just selects the folder he created for the website package to be unzipped.

Comment: Are you trying to upload (to server) or download (from server) data?
If downloading, you can't affect it using html, if uploading, you can only upload one file per input-file in html.

Answer (score 1):

Not purely by html. That is not a standard html input device. You could perhaps use something like Silverlight or Flash, but that is more involved. I'm also not sure what you would do once the user *has* selected a folder, since there is no matching concept in terms of http form data.

Answer (score 1):

For similar purpose I am using Microsoft.Web.Administration API. I presume that you don't really wont to list folders but IIS sites. This example code will render all sites on local IIS and their pshycal directories :

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
```

.
.
.

```
  ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();
  foreach (Site mySite in mgr.Sites)
    Response.Write("Site : " + mySite.Name + " -- path: " + mySite.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath + "<br />");
```